# Flutter Unable to connect to Chrome debug port

Tags: flutter

I get the following error when I run an *empty* flutter app for web.

Command run:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Error:

```
Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 50848
 SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = localhost, port = 50849
```

I tried from different flutter channels (stable, and main). Re-installed Chrome. Nothing works.

Excerpt of Flutter doctor.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel main, 3.21.0-9.0.pre.26, on macOS 12.7.2 21G1974 darwin-x64, locale en-MA)
    • Flutter version 3.21.0-9.0.pre.26 on channel main at /Users/xyz/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e7baebdce7 (2 hours ago), 2024-03-16 08:56:23 -0400
    • Engine revision e4602aa149
    • Dart version 3.4.0 (build 3.4.0-240.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.33.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was modifying `/private/etc/hosts`.

Now it looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the port like the following

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8080
//Or
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven’t tried out yet (I am on my phone) but do you know why the error is happening. It was working before until today.

Comment: Maybe because your browser lacks dart extension or the port is already in use. Not exactly sure

Comment: `flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8080` does not work. The web port does not change the debug port.

`flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080` works but this does not enable debuging.

Comment: Please use chrome dev tools for debugging. It will console everything in browser not in ide